# How do I line up decimal points correctly in C++/command based on user inputted data? Also having an issue with rounding up when its not supposed to

Tags: c++, decimal, positioning

I have been working on this prompt for school:

Write a C++ program that asks the user to enter the monthly costs for the following expenses incurred from operating your automobile: loan payment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, and maintenance. The program should then display the total monthly cost of these expenses, and a projected total annual cost of these expenses.

Label each cost.  The labels should be left aligned and have a column width of 30 characters.  The cost should be aligned right and displayed with two decimal places with a column width of 15.

If the yearly total is greater than 1000 dollars, add 10 percent of the yearly total to the yearly total.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    double loan_Payment;
    double insurance;
    double gas;
    double oil;
    double tires;
    double maintenance;


    /// text setup
    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Loan Payment" << right << "$  " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> loan_Payment;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Insurance" << right << "   " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> insurance;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Gas" << right << "   " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> gas;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Oil" << right << "   " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> oil;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Tires" << right << "   " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> tires;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Maintenance" << right << "   " << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout.width(15); cin >> right >> maintenance;

    // adding total.yearly total, 10%

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Total" << right << "$  ";

    cout.width(15); cout << left << (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance) << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

    cout.width(30); cout << left << "Yearly Total" << right << "$  ";

    cout.width(15); cout << left << (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

    
    //if yearly total is greater than 1000 add 10 percent of the yearly total
    double yearly_total;
    yearly_total = (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance));
    if (yearly_total >= 1000) 
    {
        cout.width(30); cout << left << "10%" << right << "$  ";
        cout.width(15); cout << left << (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) * .10 << fixed << setprecision(2) << left << endl;
        cout.width(30); cout << left << "Grand Total" << right << "$  " << left << ((12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) * .10) + (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

    }

        
}
```

I got this output from that code:

```
Loan Payment                  $  303.28  
Insurance                        75.00
Gas                              125.00
Oil                              45.00
Tires                            0.00
Maintenance                      15.00
Total                         $  563.28
Yearly Total                  $  6759.36
10%                           $  675.94
Grand Total                   $  7435.30
```

However the output I needed is this:

```
Loan Payment               $   303.28
Insurance                       75.00
Gas                            125.00
Oil                             45.00
Tires                            0.00
Maintenance                     15.00
Total                      $   563.28
Yearly total               $  6759.36
10%                        $   675.93
Grand Total                $  7435.29
```

As you can see the the outputs do not quite match, because the decimal places do not line up properly. I have no idea how to make this happen, because when I input the first half of the output into command prompt it does not line them up and I do not know how to set it up to where it does and the second half either. I also do not understand why its rounding up on the grand total and 10 percent portion of the output and cant find out why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the "output you need" includes the numbers the user types, you are not likely going to get the right-alignment that you ask for.  The program can't know how many spaces should be displayed before a number that hasn't been entered yet.

Comment: I think your assignment is to print the list _after_ getting reading _all_ the inputs. Read the instruction once more.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would try to put this code in a for loop and iterate through an array that would hold these numbers so you don't have to rewrite print statements over and over, but if this is the way you have to do it, just remove the first set of 'fixed' keywords and probably set the 2nd setw() to around 10.

```
double loan_payment = 303.28, insurance = 75.00, gas = 125.00, oil = 45.00, tires = 0.00, maintenance = 15.00, total = 563.28;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Loan Payment" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << loan_payment << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Insurance" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << insurance << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Gas" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << gas << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Oil" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << oil << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Tires" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << tires << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Maintenance" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << maintenance << endl;

cout << setw(30) << left << "Total" << right << "$" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << (loan_payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)`
```